# How to automate terminal inputs/commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc, automation

For example if I'm using gitlab and every time I do git pull/push etc. It shows this Username for `'https://gitlab.example.com':` so every time this text is appeared in terminal it should automatically enter the specific input. Also on a broader scale if I put a bunch of commands asking for input in sh file all the respective inputs would be entered automatically by terminal. Git is just for example here, because there exists a way to automate git by adding ssh key. Another example could be automated `scp` or `ssh`. Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, switch to Private Key/Public Key authentication.

[This guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html) will explain how to create and add a public key to GitLab, please notice that you'll have to switch your address from `https://…` to `git@gitlab.com:…`.

Regarding SSH/SCP, all you have to do is to login to the server once using the command `ssh-copy-id <user>@<host_address>` (after you've created a private key in the former GitLab guide), instead of actually logging you into the system your public key will be copied and you'll be able to use SSH/SCP without a password.